# MySQL SUM of big TIMEDIFF

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a SQL Table activity with two fields named started_at, ended_at, each being a Datetime column, and an airplane_id field.

Let's call the interval "ended_at - started_at" the duration.

My goal is, for each airplane_id, get the sum of the interval of every activity on a certain period.

Basically, it would be something like

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ended_at, started_at))))
FROM activity
WHERE started_at > :started_at
AND ended_at < :ended_at
GROUP BY airplane_id
```

The issue is that my processed period may be over the maximum time size (around 838h) and I'm seeking for an efficient workaround.

Before giving up and just extracting the raw data and processing them in PHP, I'm hoping that some SQL genius may save me.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

As I thought, there is no way to do my thing in pure SQL and it will need some PHP treatment.

So, I'll go for a massive PHP treatment.

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

How about representing the result as fractional hours or days, rather than as a time?

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ended_at, started_at))) / (60 * 60) as fractional_hours
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ended_at, started_at))) / (24 * 60 * 60) as fractional_hours
```

Personally, I don't see much value in using a time format for such large intervals of time.

Comment: I thought about using Date format but i need to get at least a precision in minutes and Datediff gives me only days.
If you have a better suggestion, i'm open :)

Comment: @Mouke . . . I don't understand the comment.  This answer produces decimal hours and days.

Comment: The issue with Decimal is that it's not readable for a human. You can't tell easily how many minutes makes 0.42 of an hour.
So basically it would need a PHP formatting after that, which my boss wants to avoid.

Comment: @Mouke . . . It seems like an odd problem where some time frames are measured in months and someone is worried about minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `timestampdiff()`?

```
SELECT sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, ended_at, started_at))
       FROM activity
...
```

That returns an `integer`, so you wouldn't have to deal with the limits of `time` (But with those of `integer` of course.) And you won't need that conversion to seconds, as you already can get the result in seconds.

Comment: The whole idea is to fetch usable data from SQL without using PHP (in clear, PHP would fetch the array with the data already formatted) in order to export them into a CSV file.

So basically, the whole point is to have "readable" data for end-user, hence the HH:MM format.